# Convert vector<double> to vector<string> ( elegant way )

Tags: c++, string, vector, double

I would like to know if there is an elegant way or a built-in function to convert `vector<double>` to `vector<string>`. What I've done is simple

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>


std::vector<std::string> doubeVecToStr(const std::vector<double>& vec)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tempStr;

    for (unsigned int i(0); i < vec.size(); ++i){
        std::ostringstream doubleStr;
        doubleStr << vec[i];    
        tempStr.push_back(doubleStr.str());
    }

    return tempStr;
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::vector<double> doubleVec;
    doubleVec.push_back(1.0);
    doubleVec.push_back(2.1);
    doubleVec.push_back(3.2);

    std::vector<std::string> doubleStr;
    doubleStr = doubeVecToStr(doubleVec);

    for (unsigned int i(0); i < doubleStr.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << doubleStr[i] << "  ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind using Boost, you can use this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.join_hpp

Comment: Why do you need a vector of strings? Why not just convert the float when needed?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, sorry about that but it is an absolute coincidence. I did consider another answer that suits this question. sorry again.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are many ways, but a standard solution is to use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda using [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for the conversion :

```
std::transform(std::begin(doubleVec),
               std::end(doubleVec), 
               std::back_inserter(doubleStr),
               [](double d) { return std::to_string(d); } 
              );
```

And you can wrap that in a function template to make it work with any Standard compliant container :

```
template<class IteratorIn, class IteratorOut>
void to_string(IteratorIn first, IteratorIn last, IteratorOut out)
{
    std::transform(first, last, out,
                   [](typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIn>::value_type d) { return std::to_string(d); } );
}
```

Or in **C++14**, with a generic lambda :

```
template<class IteratorIn, class IteratorOut>
void to_string(IteratorIn first, IteratorIn last, IteratorOut out)
{
    std::transform(first, last, out, [](auto d) { return std::to_string(d); } );
}
```

And call it with any container (i.e. it works with `std::list<int>`, for instance) :

```
to_string(std::begin(doubleVec), std::end(doubleVec), std::back_inserter(doubleStr));
```

---

**Notes :**

- If you don't have a C++11 compiler, write your own `to_string` function template :

Example:

```
template<class T>
std::string my_to_string(T v)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << v;
    return ss.str();
}
```

And use it in a similar way :

```
std::transform(doubleVec.begin(),
               doubleVec.end(),
               std::back_inserter(doubleStr), 
               my_to_string<double> );
```

- You should [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the memory in the output vector to avoid reallocations during `std::transform()` :

e.g. do this :

```
std::vector<std::string> stringVec;
stringVec.reserve(v.size());   // reserve space for v.size() elements
```

---

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76f397afed2f9b60)

Comment: std::begin(doubleVec), std::end(doubleVec)?

Comment: No need for a lambda here.

Comment: Or maybe there is, because it's overloaded function, and requires an ugly cast otherwise.

Comment: @Neil Yes ! (and even if it doesn't, it shows the OP how to call its own conversion function if he needs to)

Comment: In addition, it makes sure the call can be inlined and will not go through a function-pointer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It doesn't "make sure" of anything of the kind. Though it does make it much more likely.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It won't be indirected through a function-pointer that way. And that makes it much more likely it will be inlined. Think that's better?

Comment: @Deduplicator Function pointers can be inlined if the function is known at compile-time.

Comment: `std::to_string` is this in C++11? I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: @CroCo This is C++11 solution I'm afraid.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Sure, but avoiding them makes inlining much more likely.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, if you have a bad compiler.

Comment: @CroCo Please see my note (generic solution, not just for `double`)

Answer (score 5):

Using `copy` and `ostream_iterator`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> numbers{1.0, 2.1, 3.2};
  std::stringstream output;
  std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(output, " "));

  std::cout << output.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't output a vector of strings.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Good point. Although, OP converts the vector to string anyway. If it's not what he wants, I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you have a container of `T` and want to create a container of `U` from the container of `T`, as others have mentioned the algorithm to look for is `std::transform`.

If you are not using C++ 11, Here is `std::transform` usage:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

std::string Transformer(double d)
{
    std::ostringstream doubleStr;
    doubleStr << d;
    return doubleStr.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> doubleVec;
    doubleVec.push_back(1.0);
    doubleVec.push_back(2.1);
    doubleVec.push_back(3.2);

    std::vector<std::string> doubleStr;
    std::transform(doubleVec.begin(), doubleVec.end(), std::back_inserter(doubleStr), Transformer);
    std::copy(doubleStr.begin(), doubleStr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "  "));
}
```

Output:
`1  2.1  3.2`