# Pass template function to transform without lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I currently have the c++11 function:

```
template<class IteratorIn>
std::string to_string_join(IteratorIn first, IteratorIn last, std::string joiner) {

    std::vector<std::string> ss(last - first);

    std::transform(
        first, last, begin(ss),
        [](typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIn>::value_type d) {
            return std::to_string(d);
        }
    );

    return boost::algorithm::join(ss, joiner);
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
std::vector<int> is{-1, 2, 62, 4, -86, 23, 8, -0,2};

std::cout << to_string_join(begin(is), end(is), ", ") << std::endl;
```

To output :

> "-1, 2, 62, 4, -86, 23, 8, 0 ,2".

I read in another SO post ["convert-vectordouble-to-vectorstring-elegant-way"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371873/convert-vectordouble-to-vectorstring-elegant-way/25371915#25371915) that the lambda is not required. However I haven't been able to achieve removing the lambda.

I suspect it should look similar to this:

```
std::transform(
    first, last, begin(ss),
    std::to_string<typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIn>::value_type>
);
```

That results in the compilation error:

> "error: expected ‘(’ before ‘>’ token".

How can I go about passing to_string without the lambda?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error occurs because [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is not a function template. You're looking for a `static_cast`, not a template argument.

```
std::transform(
    first, last, begin(ss),
    static_cast<std::string(*)(typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIn>::value_type)>(std::to_string)
);
```

Comment: Correct you are, it is a shame it is so messy. Thank you.

Comment: @JulianAustralia Yep, messy it is; just stick to the lambda.